# Required field after submit else

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, submit

I made this piece of code to check after submit if a field is filled in. If it's not, my script adds a class for red border and a popup under it that says: Fill in the field. But I want if I fill in the field the error class removes and the popup fades out.

```
$("#frmQ").submit(function(){
    if ($(".zipcode").val() == "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".zipcode").addClass('req_error');
        $(".req_pop").fadeIn(200);
    }
    else {
        $(".zipcode").removeClass('req_error');
        $(".req_pop").fadeOut(200);
    }
})
```

My validation works but after I fill in the required field the class and popup don't go away.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: because you are doing your else statement on value exists after submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code:

```
$(".zipcode").keydown(function(){
$(this).removeClass('req_error');
$(".req_pop").fadeOut(200);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(".zipcode").removeClass('req_error');
```

instead of

```
$(".req_pop").hide();
```